# Use bind operator to curry a function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-next

Given that `this.handler.bind(this)` can be replaced with `::this.handler`, how can I replace `this.handler.bind(this, 1)` using `::`?

I found this useful in a situation where I want to attach handlers to react components. E.g.:

```
handler(x) {
  this.setState({counter: x})
}

<a onClick={this.handler.bind(this, 5)}>increment by 5</a>
```

I know that I can use `_.curry` (lodash) but it's pretty much the same in terms of code readability:

```
<a onClick={_.curry(::this.handler, 5)}>increment by 5</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ES next draft for the bind operator](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-bind-operator) does not feature partial application as it is currently specced. Just continue to use `bind` (`this.handler.bind(this, 5)` or a simple arrow function `e => this.handler(5, e)`.